# Invoking Rterm without specifying R file

Tags: r, invoke, rterm

I'm new to R and trying to understand the following code from a bat file. From what I've read, to use Rterm, you need to specify an input file with R extension i.e. xyz.R. However, these codes run just fine even though no R extension is specified. Am I missing something here? I also cannot find any file withe the name as specified in the code i.e. read-inbound-crop, read-inbound-weather, calculate-result and export-result.

```
@echo off

Rexec "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\Rterm.exe" read-inbound-crop --args current
Rexec "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\Rterm.exe" read-inbound-weather --args current
Rexec "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\Rterm.exe" calculate-result --args current
Rexec "E:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64\Rterm.exe" export-result --args current
```